# Simple Push Button Code

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I am trying to create a program that prints 1 then 2 then 3 in a label when I click a push button. However, it seems that the window shows only after completing the loop, thereby printing only 3.

#### My Code:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
qtCreatorFile = "sample.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class sample(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.loop)

    def loop(self):
        i=0
        while i!=3:
            if i==1:
                self.status.setText(str(i))
                time.sleep(1)
            if i==3:
                self.status.setText(str(i))
                time.sleep(1)
            i+=1

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = sample()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm using python3.5

Comment: GUI works different - there is some function (called `mainloop`) which gets key/mouse events, sends data to widgets, redraws widgets. When you run long-running function then `mainloop` can't work - it waits for the end of your function. Most GUI has function -  timer - which adds `time` and `function name` to special list and `mainloop` execute it at `time`. This way you don't stop `mainloop` (and you don't need `sleep()`). Second method is to run your loop in separated thread.

Comment: Thank you. I can't seem to find any article about the function mainloop. Do you have anything that would help me study this function? thanks.